# Transform deeply nested ruby hash

Tags: ruby, algorithm, hash

I have a deeply nested Ruby hash which I need to transform into another hash. A Hash might have 0 or more children. **Here's the input hash:**

```
"{'id' => 'apple', 'children' => [{'id' => 'ipad', 'children' => [{'id' => 'ipadmini'}]},{'id' => 'ipadmini'}]}"
```

**output**

```
[{"ipad"=>{"id"=>"ipad", "paths"=>[[{"id"=>"apple"}, {"id"=>"ipad"}]]}},
{"ipadmini"=>{"id"=>"ipadmini", "paths"=>[[{"id"=>"ipad"}, {"id"=>"ipadmini"}], [{"id"=>"apple"}, {"id"=>"ipad"}, {"id"=>"ipadmini"}]]}}, {"apple"=>{"id"=>"apple", "paths"=>[[{"id"=>"apple"}]]}}]
```

**my code:**

```
def construct_concept(concept)
    h = {}
    c = Hash[*concept.to_a.first]
    c['paths'] = [[Hash[*concept.to_a.first]]]
    h[concept['id']] = c
    h
end

def parent_child_concepts(concepts)
    pc = {}
    pc[:parent] = Hash[*concepts.first]
    pc[:children] = concepts.values_at('children').flatten.map {|child| parent_child_concepts(child)} || []
    pc
end

def add_parent_child_paths(parent_hash,children_array)
    h = {}
    parent_hash.each do |parent_key,parent_value|
        h[parent_key] = parent_value
        children_array.each do |child|
            child.each do |k,v|
                h[k] = v
                h[k]['paths'].map {|path| path.unshift({'id' => parent_key})}
            end
        end
    end
    h
end

def build_concept_data(concepts)
    #concept {"id"=>"apple", "children"=>[{"id"=>"ipad"}]}
    parsed_concepts = parent_child_concepts(concepts)
    parent = construct_concept(parsed_concepts[:parent])
    children = parsed_concepts[:children].each_with_object([]) {|child,accu| accu << construct_concept(child)}
    concept_paths_data = add_parent_child_paths(parent,children)
end
```

Comment: So what did your first attempt to solve this problem look like?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dasibre/0f1de48590064e4126440b7c4933cd10 first attempt.

Comment: It's ideal to put code like that in your question itself. You can edit to amend.

Comment: Do you actually have a question? All I can see is a statement which makes it impossible to answer

Comment: I'm unable to solve the problem. I can't seem to convert it to the necessary output? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I guess a better question is how to loop through a deeply nested hash with array of hashes, recursively to create a new hash with new keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def build_data(node, ctx = [], result = [])
  id = node['id']
  children = node['children']

  branch = result.find{|h| h.has_key?(id)}
  if branch.nil?
    result.push({
      id => {
        'id' => id,
        'paths' => []
      }
    })
  end
  branch = result.find{|h| h.has_key?(id)}
  branch[id]['paths'].unshift(
    [ctx, id].flatten.map do |ctx_id|
      {
        'id' => ctx_id
      }
    end
  )

  if children.is_a?(Array)
    children.each do |node|
      new_ctx = ctx.dup
      new_ctx.push(id)
      nesting(node, new_ctx, result)
    end
  end

  result
end
```